# auto refresh text box value

Tags: javascript, html

I've multiple text field HTML,  I'm getting value from other page this value is dynamic it'll keep on change, So I need to auto refresh my text box every one sec, is that possible to refresh only text box value

note: IO.html has var1, var2 etc.. variables values will keep on change.., I need to track this values in Intex.html text box

```js
    <script type="text/javascript">
              setInterval(function () {
                  $.getJSON("IO.html", function (data) {
                      if (data.var1 == true) {
                          $('#C1-Cycle').text(data.trim());
                      }
                  });
              }, 1000);
            </script>
```

```html
index.html
<html>
  <head>
    </head>
  <body>
    <table>
     <tr >
            <td class="C3-tap-col">
            <div>
            <input type="text" id="C1-Cycle" class="C3-tap-tex" value=''>
            Counter
            </div>
            </td>      
     </tr>
      </table>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: try  $('#C1-Cycle').val(data.trim());

Comment: T4mer: It did't work, but we are in the correct track, we need to focus on post value to text field using javascript (json),

Comment: What is the output of `data`? You say it is an HTML page, so why does it return a JSON response?

Comment: Let I explain, var1 will retrieve the value from PLC machine, it is a counter,  html page will interact with PLC machine and retrieve the data in every seconds, I'm trying to post the value in text box of another html page, now values are retrieved json also worked with label id, I'm trying to do the same with text box..

Comment: if you want to refresh whole page than it is possible...will it do

Comment: No I can't, value will change for sure., but it's annoying because I've other objects in the page (images etc), that's why I need to refresh that particular text box value

Comment: Maybe $('#C1-Cycle').val(data.trim()) does not work because you never closed your input tag.

Comment: if there is data.var1 then data is object, how you are setting object value to textbox ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, with the new information I rebuilt your example one to one.

We have a file with values called IO.html containing variables in non array json format:

```
{"var1": "30", "var2": "40"}
```

Then we have the file index.html which is supposed to read the values of IO.html each second and enter the values in their input fields in index.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            AJAX = {
                getXmlDoc: function(){return ((window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"))},

                //u:= url, f:= callback
                Get: function(u, f){
                    var tDoc = this.getXmlDoc();

                    tDoc.open('GET', u, true);
                    tDoc.onreadystatechange = function(){
                        if (tDoc.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && tDoc.status === 200) f(tDoc);
                    };

                    tDoc.send();
                }
            };
        </script>

        <script type = 'text/javascript'>
            function startTimer(){
                document.body.QQ = setInterval(function(){
                    AJAX.Get('IO.html', function(r){
                        var tR = eval('[' + r.response + ']')[0]; //This is our json object of IO.html (:= {"var1": "30", "var2": "40"})

                        //Now we loop all values/key in our json and add it to the input with that id (:= var1, var2)
                        for(var k in tR){
                            //We get the input with the same id as the key..
                            //We could also create them on the fly.
                            var tE = document.getElementById(k);
                            if (tE) tE.value = tR[k];
                        }
                    })
                }, 1000)
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload = 'startTimer()'>
        <input type = 'text' id = 'var1' name = 'C1-Cycle' />
        <input type = 'text' id = 'var2' name = 'C2-Cycle' />
    </body>
</html>
```

So now you load the index.html and each second it gets the new values from IO.html and updates the values of IO.html in the input fields of index.html.

Why the same code as the fiddle works in fiddle yet not on your server I am not able to tell you. Usually some path is wrong or some includes missing.
Be aware that locally you are not able to access "/echo/js/?js={"var1": "30", "var2": "40"}".

Here is a futher example with placeholder and iframe.
First the IO.html which updates every second via meta refresh:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv = 'refresh' content = '5'>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type = 'text' value = ':="Datablock".counter:' />
    </body
</html>
```

And the index.html containing the IO.html in an iframe:

```
<html>
    <head></head>

    <body>
        <iframe src = 'IO.html'></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79772/discussion-on-answer-by-lain-auto-refresh-text-box-value).